# Problem with drawing a Pythagoras Tree using L-system and production rules

Tags: processing

I am drawing a Pythagoras Tree using L-system and 2 production rules. I managed to use the first rule called “F-rule” to draw the right handside of the tree. I tried using the second rule “H-rule” to draw the left handside. NO matter what I change in the H-rule, it messes up the result of the right handside. Any idea how I can create the leftside similar to the right ? Many thanks.

```
    int SZ = 800;  
Tree tree;
  
void settings() {
  size(SZ,SZ);  
}

void setup() {
  int d = 100;
  int x = SZ/2;
  int y = SZ/2;
  float branchAngle = radians(180);
  float branchAngle_Left = radians(-45); 
  float branchAngle_Right = radians(45); 
  float initOrientation = PI;  
  String state = "F";   // initiator        
  float  scaleFactor = 0.8;      
  String F_rule = "F[+sH]s+F";      
  String H_rule = "";  
  String f_rule = "";           
  int numIterations = 6;
  
  background(255);
  noLoop();
  
 tree = new Tree(d, x, y, branchAngle, branchAngle_Right, branchAngle_Left, initOrientation, state, scaleFactor, F_rule, H_rule, f_rule, numIterations);  
}

void draw() {
  tree.draw();
  }

    class Tree {

 
  int    m_lineLength;       // turtle line length
  int    m_x;                // initial x position
  int    m_y;                // initial y position
  float  m_branchAngle_Right;      // turtle rotation at branch
  float  m_branchAngle_Left;      // turtle rotation at branch
  float  m_branchAngle;
  float  m_initOrientation;  // initial orientation
  String m_state;            // initial state
  float  m_scaleFactor;      // branch scale factor
  String m_F_rule;           // F-rule substitution
  String m_H_rule;           // H-rule substitution
  String m_f_rule;           // f-rule substitution
  int    m_numIterations;    // number of times to substitute
  
  // constructor
  // (d = line length, x & y = start position of drawing)
  Tree(int d, int x, int y, float branchAngle, float branchAngle_Right, float branchAngle_Left, float initOrientation, String state, float scaleFactor, 
  String F_rule, String H_rule, String f_rule, int numIterations) {
    m_lineLength = d;
    m_x = x;
    m_y = y; 
    m_branchAngle= branchAngle;
    m_branchAngle_Right = branchAngle_Right;
    m_branchAngle_Left = branchAngle_Left;
    m_initOrientation = initOrientation;
    m_state = state;
    m_scaleFactor = scaleFactor;
    m_F_rule = F_rule;
    m_H_rule = H_rule;
    m_f_rule = f_rule;
    m_numIterations = numIterations;

    // Perform L rounds of substitutions on the initial state
    for (int k=0; k < m_numIterations; k++) {
      m_state = substitute(m_state);
    }
  }
  
  void draw() {
    pushMatrix();
    pushStyle();
    
    stroke(0);
    translate(m_x, m_y);        // initial position
    rotate(m_initOrientation);  // initial rotation
    
    
    for (int i=0; i < m_state.length(); i++) {
      turtle(m_state.charAt(i));
    }
    
    popStyle();
    popMatrix();
  }
  
  
  void turtle(char c) {
    switch(c) {
    case 'F': // drop through to next case
    case 'H':
    //line (0, 0, 0, m_lineLength);
      rect(0, 0, m_lineLength, m_lineLength);
      translate(0, m_lineLength);
      break;
    case 'f':
      translate(0, m_lineLength);
      break;
      case 't':
      translate(0, -m_lineLength);
      break;
    case 's':
      scale(m_scaleFactor);
      break;
    case '&':
      rotate(m_branchAngle);
      break;
    case '-':
      rotate(m_branchAngle_Left);
      break;
    case '+':
      rotate(m_branchAngle_Right);
      break;
    case '[':
      pushMatrix();
      break;
    case ']':
      popMatrix();
      break;
    default:
      println("Bad character: " + c);
      exit();
    }
  }
  
  // apply substitution rules to string s and return the resulting string
  String substitute(String s) {
    String newState = new String();
    for (int j=0; j < s.length(); j++) {
      switch (s.charAt(j)) {
      case 'F':
        newState += m_F_rule;
        break;
      case 'H':
        newState += m_H_rule;
        break;
      case 'f':
        newState += m_f_rule;
        break;
      default:
        newState += s.charAt(j);
      }
    }
    return newState;
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagoras_tree_(fractal)), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fSqHBnXrKc), [3](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PythagorasTree.html), [4](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Pythagoras_tree#Processing), [5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Ih8LuIJ_go)) I have arrived to a few conclusions. However, I haven't been able to find the H and F rules anywhere.

1. First of all I wouldn't recomend you setting two different angles since they are dependant as they form a right triangle. `branchAngle_Right = 90 - branchAngle_Left`
2. Moreover, for 45º, the fact that the scale factor is √2/2 (and not 0,8) is not arbitrary. It's due to trygonometric consequences. If we wanted to generalize it would be something like this: `m_scaleFactor_Right = cos(m_branchAngle_Right)`, and the same for left.
3. Finally, i would try to redo, the tree generation as it seems to me that it has been overcomplicated. The fourth and the fith (in the coments) references atached at the begining are example codes. See how, in the fith one, it is being calculated the position of the new square and not translating from the previous square, which may be the cause of your problems when doing the left side backwards.

However, i do thing your code could work, but the efford you would put into it would be much larger than doing it from the begining and not overcomplicating.

If you still want to continue that way, please attach some information about those rules you were saying so we can help you.